# How to sort a collection by reputation and creation date

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

Assuming I want to sort a list of users by reputation:

1. User with 5 reputation
2. User with 3 reputation
3. User with 0 reputation (this user was registered before the 4th user)
4. User with 0 reputation

By doing `$query->get()->sortByDesc('reputation')`, I receive the following results:

1. User with 5 reputation
2. User with 3 reputation
3. User with 0 reputation
4. User with 0 reputation (this user was registered before the 4th user)

How can I sort the collection to receive results similar to the first example? In other words, if users have 0 reputation, how can I change the sorting method to creation date by descending order?

Answer (score 2):

Chain two `orderBy()` methods inside the query:

```
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('reputation', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but it still doesn't produce the expected results.

Comment: Did you try second one? Make sure to remove `sortByDesc()` code.

Comment: Yea, I also tried the second one, could it be possible that it's affected from a mutator? I'm using a getReputationAttribute method to return the sum from multiple factors.

Comment: I don't think so. I've just tried `orderBy()` and it works as expected.

Comment: I'll give it a second try and let you know.

Comment: I'm not sure why are you getting this. I'm sorting a simple list of countries first by `region` and then by `name`. Works as expected. Check your code once again, maybe you have some piece of code which modifies result or something? If you'll make this work please tell me how did you solve the problem.

Comment: Yea, I will look more into it and when I get this working I'll let you know.

Comment: After setting up a test page, it works on windows but not on ubuntu (server)

Comment: I guess the problem is in different MySQL settings. You should ask another question with `MySQL` tag so guys who are really good with this DB could help.

Comment: It appears that I was using an older version on the server so I downgraded to that version. It seems that on PHP 5 double sorting doesn't work very well using sortBy/orderBy. With that, I used the sort method and passed in a callback which sorts the collection by reputation. If the two items being compared don't have reputation, I check for their id to make sure the user that registered first appears before the other one. Thanks for your help.